# How to embed a translator on a site

Tags: html, translation, embed

I am a foreign language teacher whos class does not have dictionaries. But we have a smartboard. I have all my tools and tasks for the students on a custom site similar to classroomscreen.com.

What I am missing is a way to embed translator.google.com or a similar translation website into my site, so students can write onto the smartboard for everyone else to see the translation.

What would be the right approach?

I tried the  tag and adding deepl.com, but to make the input bar visible I need to make the  way to large. All the unnecessary adds and banners show.

It would be optimal if there only was an input prompt and a list of results of the translation. Some JS accessing an API ...

But I am clueless about what to use in which way.